# API to access referrer field in Apache Module

Tags: apache2, apache-modules

I cannot find it in the request_rec* structure? Is there a way by which I can access it in the Apache Module?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The referer is stored in the request header, so you should get the referer from there:

```
const char* referer = apr_table_get(request->headers_in, "Referer");
```

Answer (score 0):

You should

```
#apt-get install apache2-prefork-dev
```

then

```
#apxs2 -gn Somename
```

mod_Somename.c is in your **Somename** directory. In this .c file contains **request_rec*** structure.
if you want to try full reference of request_rec* is following link

http://ci.apache.org/projects/httpd/trunk/doxygen/httpd_8h.html

Answer (score 0):

you can access request_rec* in input/output filter functions of an Apache 2.x Module:

**for input filters**:

```
int do_nothing_input_filter(ap_filter_t *f, apr_bucket_brigade *bb, ap_input_mode_t mode, apr_read_type_e block,
apr_off_t readbytes)
{
    request_rec *r = f->r;
    (...)
}
```

**for output filters:**

```
apr_status_t my_output_filter_func(ap_filter_t* f, apr_bucket_brigade* bb)
{
    request_rec *r = f->r;
    (...)
}
```

the structure is defined in httpd.h [reference of Apache 2.x doxygen documentation](http://ci.apache.org/projects/httpd/trunk/doxygen/structrequest__rec.html)